# Getting the validation group of an erroneous form field in Twig

Tags: validation, symfony, twig

When looping through my form errors in Twig:

```
{% for error in form.vars.errors %}
    {{ dump(error) }}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I determine the validation groups of each constraint that is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out shortly after posting, I needed `error.cause.constraint.groups`. Like so:

```
{% for error in form.vars.errors %}
    {% for group in error.cause.constraint.groups %}
        {{ group }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```